# Identify IC "VY"

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification

Can anyone help me identify IC "VY" as pictured?

[image: Photo of IC]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Nexperia 74LVC1G19](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Nexperia-74LVC1G19GW-125_C148208.pdf) decoder/demultiplexer.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Signal-Switches-Encoders-Decoders-Multiplexers_Nexperia-74LVC1G19GW-125_C148208.html))